# Почему не работает склонение час/часа/часов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу чтобы при каждой генерации нового числа к нему добавлялось час/часа/часов назад.
Сейчас выводится второй вариант "часа", т.е 23 часа, 5 часа и т.д.

Собственно вопрос, что необходимо поставить вместо 2, чтобы определялось число `getRandomNumber` и склонения были правильными?

```js
function declOfNum(number, titles) {
  cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
  return titles[(number % 100 > 4 && number % 100 < 20) ? 2 : cases[(number % 10 < 5) ? number % 10 : 5]];
}

window.onload = function fillDiv() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.vertical__date').forEach(el => {
    const number = getRandomNumber(1, 24) + declOfNum(2, [' час', ' часа', ' часов']) + ' назад';
    el.textContent = number;
  })
}

function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  const numbers = [...document.querySelectorAll('.vertical__date')].map(el => +el.textContent || 0);
  let random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  return !numbers.includes(random_number) ? random_number : getRandomNumber(min, max);
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical__date"></div>
<div class="vertical__date"></div>
<div class="vertical__date"></div>
<div class="vertical__date"></div>
```

Comment: `declOfNum(2, [' час', ' часа', ' часов'])` — ты его всегда вызываешь для числа `2`, и получаешь `[2] часа`.

Comment: Очевидно надо результат `getRandomNumber(1,24)` запомнить в переменную и передавать эту переменную.

Comment: Я про это и спрашиваю, как это осуществить, помогите пожалуйста новичку)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если минимально редактировать исходный вариант, получается так:

```js
function declOfNum(number, titles) {
  cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
  return titles[(number % 100 > 4 && number % 100 < 20) ? 2 : cases[(number % 10 < 5) ? number % 10 : 5]];
}

window.onload = function fillDiv() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.vertical__date').forEach(el => {
    const number = getRandomNumber(1, 24);
    const text = number + declOfNum(number, [' час', ' часа', ' часов']) + ' назад';
    el.textContent = text;
  })
}

function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  const numbers = [...document.querySelectorAll('.vertical__date')].map(el => +el.textContent || 0);
  let random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  return !numbers.includes(random_number) ? random_number : getRandomNumber(min, max);
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical__date"></div>
<div class="vertical__date"></div>
<div class="vertical__date"></div>
<div class="vertical__date"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Оказалось все так просто!

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
window.onload = function fillDiv(){
  document.querySelectorAll('.vertical__date').forEach(el => {
    const h = getRandomNumber(1,24);
    const number = h + declOfNum(h, [' час', ' часа', ' часов']) + ' назад';
    el.textContent = number;
  })  
}
```

И да, у вас в примере не используется библиотека jquery - наверное тег лучше в вопросе убрать.